How to sum up all ascii values of elements in a stack in assembly x86
At this point i feel pretty lost, that's why my code looks like that
org 100h

start:
    xor ax, ax          
    xor dx, dx          
    mov ah, 1           
    xor cx, cx          

input:
    int 21h             
    cmp al, '+'         
    jz sum          

    push ax             
    inc cx              
    jmp input      

sum:
    push bp              
    mov bp, sp           
    mov cx, [bp+4]       
    mov si, 6            
    xor ax, ax          

sum_loop:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov ax, [bp+6]
    mov bx, [bp + 4]
    add ax, bx
    mov [result], ax
    pop ax
    loop sum_loop 
    pop bp; 
    ret

print:
    mov al, [result]
    mov bl, 10
    div bl
    mov [pt_one], ah
    
    xor ah, ah
    
    div bl
    mov [pt_two], ah
    xor ah, ah
    
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    
    mov al, [pt_two]
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    xor al, al
    
    mov al, [pt_one]
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
    
section .data
    pt_one db 1
    pt_two db 1
    result db 0

Here I'm sure that part with input is working, but I can't figure out if it's either my faulty summing protocol or my way fo printing is bad. In summing I try to add 2 next elements and add it to result variable, then remove top of the stack. When I try this code (Usually I go with input 123+) and I put + nothing happens and I frankly have no idea how to fix it.

It would immensely help if you add comments with intent of code segments,  because now they don't make a lot of rhyme and reason. E.g. In the sum portion, you overwrite cx counter, and sum_loop doesn't make a lot of sense in general

the part where I overwrite the cx is something I found on web to copy element on [bp+4] to cx since it supposed to be amount of elements, the sum_loop is something I try to use to make the loop, because I couldn't quite figure out how to to do it in one protocol.

One problem is caused by ret instruction. ret pops address from stack and loads it into program counter. But you never call this code as a function, so stack doesn't contain any valid return address. The program jumps to "random" address, in particular to 0100h ORed with ASCII code of last input character before +. If your input is 123+, the bogus address is 0133h. Casually it happened that there is mov bl, 10 instruction, so mov al, [result] is skipped. Then div bl tries to divide ax by 10, but ax value depends on initial bp value (after push bp / pop ax) which is undefined in general.
There are other issues with the code:

Values pushed to stack are 16-bit words containing ASCII code in low byte and 01h in high byte. You are adding them as 16-bit words including high byte, then divide resulting 16-bit value in ax by 10. I suppose this is not what you want.
If no characters are entered before +, loop makes 65536 iterations.
etc...

The program can be simplified: keep temporary values in registers instead of storing them to memory. I assume the goal is to explicitly iterate over stack, without poping values or adding them directly on each input iteration without storing them into memory. In this case complete program can be the following:
org 100h

start:
    mov ah, 1
    xor cx, cx

input:
    int 21h
    cmp al, '+'
    jz sum

    push ax
    inc cx
    jmp input

sum:
    mov bp, sp  ; bp points to stack top
    xor ax, ax  ; initial sum is 0

    jcxz print  ; skip if no characters entered

sum_loop:
    add al, [bp]    ; add low byte only
    ; hint: you also can `adc ah, 0` here to get 16-bit sum in ax
    add bp, 2       ; next 16-bit word
    loop sum_loop

print:
    mov sp, bp    ; restore initial stack pointer
    ; ah is already zeroed

    ; the rest of code is unchanged
    mov bl, 10
    div bl
    mov [pt_one], ah

    xor ah, ah

    div bl
    mov [pt_two], ah
    xor ah, ah
    
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov al, [pt_two]
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    xor al, al

    mov al, [pt_one]
    add al, 48
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

section .data
    pt_one db 1
    pt_two db 1


You're adding the ASCII codes of each number. Probably you should convert them to numeric codes instead.

Thanks big time, for explaining. Assembly is a bit confusing, but your instruction are goated. Once again thanks

@ecm OP asks for "ascii values" in the question. Sure, it is possible to substract 30h (or AND with 0Fh)  to get numbers from digit characters. But then question about handling of non-digit characters arises.
